# Understanding [object object] in React, Passing 1 component to another

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Currently, I'm passing one component to another but I'm receiving a [object object] error. I haven't been able to figure out what is causing the issue so far.
[image]

I built out an Accordion component that I'm calling in a Report component, when I call the Accordion I pass my Schedule component as a prop.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

import Chevron from "./Chevron";
import "./Accordion.css";

function Accordion(props) {
    const [setActive, setActiveState] = useState("");
    const [setHeight, setHeightState] = useState("0px");
    const [setRotate, setRotateState] = useState("accordion__icon");

    const content = useRef(null);

    function toggleAccordion() {
        setActiveState(setActive === "" ? "active" : "");
        setHeightState(
            setActive === "active" ? "0px" : `${content.current.scrollHeight}px`
        );
        setRotateState(
            setActive === "active" ? "accordion__icon" : "accordion__icon rotate"
        );
    }

    return (
        <div className="accordion__section">
            <button className={`accordion ${setActive}`} onClick={toggleAccordion}>
                <p className="accordion__title">{props.title}</p>
                <Chevron className={`${setRotate}`} width={10} fill={"#777"} />
            </button>
            <div ref={content} style={{ maxHeight: `${setHeight}` }} className="accordion__content">
                <div
                    className="accordion__text"
                    dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.content }}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Accordion;
```

This is my Report component:

```
import React from 'react';
import DebtSummary from './DebtSummary.jsx';
import Schedule from './Schedule.jsx';
import Accordion from "./accordion/Accordion";

class Report extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (<div className="report">

                <Accordion
                    title="View your credit card payment schedule"
                    content={<Schedule schedule={Result.schedule} />}
                />

                <DebtSummary cards={this.props.cards} addExtra={this.props.addExtra}/>

            </div>
        </div>);
    }
}
export default Report;
```

Here is my Schedule component:

```
import React from 'react';
import Format from './helpers/format.js';
class Schedule extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className="payment-schedule">
                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th></th>
                            <th>Payment</th>
                            <th>Interest</th>
                            <th>Total Principal</th>
                            <th>Balance</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        {this.props.schedule.map((singleSchedule, i) => {
                            return (<tr key={i}>
                                <th>{i ? i : ''}</th>
                                <td>{Format.usd(singleSchedule.payment * 100, false)}</td>
                                <td>{Format.usd(singleSchedule.interest, false)}</td>
                                <td>{Format.usd(singleSchedule.principal, false)}</td>
                                <td>{Format.usd(singleSchedule.balance * 100, false)}</td>
                            </tr>);
                        })}
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export default Schedule;
```

Currently `prop.content` a object.
[image]

If I change `props.content` to `props.content.props.schedule` I receive this display instead.
[image]
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: `[object Object]` is what you get, when you force an object into a string context (and it doesn’t have its own toString method, that would transform it into string form in a different way.) Looks like the place where that is happening here, is likely `dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: props.content }}` - so go figure out what `props.content` actually is/contains at that point first of all.

Comment: I updated the bottom of the question to show what I receive when I console.log `props.content` @CBroe

Comment: I don't see where you're invoking `<Report />`?

Comment: I'm calling invoking `Accordion`  instead `Report`  @HoldOffHunger

Answer (score 0):

The content defined in the accordion is the react element. So, you just need to render that element instead of dangerously set html.

```
<div className="accordion__text">
    { props.content }
</div>
```

Comment: When I remove dangerously set html and place `{propr.content}` or `{...props.content.props.schedule}` Nothing is displayed . I also don't receive any error

Comment: Check Result.Schedule